# Не могу разобраться с ajax + django

Tags: ajax, django

в общем есть форма регистрации, после заполнения которой приходит код на почту и перекидывает на другую форму, которую я рендарю и вставляю на эту же страницу. Вот ajax запрос:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { $("#my_form").submit(function(event) 
        { event.preventDefault(); 
            $this = $(this); 
            $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        data: $this.serialize(), 
        success: function(data) 
        { console.log(data); 
         var parent=$("#my_form").parent();
         parent.html(data.success); 
       }, 
       error: function(data) 
       { console.log(data);
         $this.html(data); 
       } 
     }); 
    }); 
});
```

после этого запроса на этой же странице вставляется такой код html

```
<form action="{%url 'endreg' %}" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{rs}}
  <div class="verification" >
    <div class="ver">
     {{form}}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'Отправить' %}" class="btn" > 
   </div>  
</form>
```

в action указываю url на котором весит обработчик сравнения кода
вот сам обработчик(как я понял это надо если вставлять форму с другой html страницы)

```
def endreg(request):
    name = request.session.get("phone", " ")
    name1 = request.session.get("code", " ")
    name2 = request.session.get("purpose", " ")
    name3 = request.session.get("date_visit", " ")
    name4 = request.session.get("time_visit", " ")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
            if (name1 == code_use):
                try:
                    user = Registration.objects.get(phone=name,purpose=name2,date_visit=name3,time_visit=name4)
                    user.verification = True
                    user.save() 
                    return JsonResponse({ 'success': 'thanks'})
                except:
                    return JsonResponse({ 'success': 'error'})
    else:
        form = NameForm1()
    return render(request, 'registers/endreg.html','form': form})
```

вопрос в том как мне обработать вторую форму с помощью ajax. Надо писать еще один ajax запрос(форме пробовал  дать другой id и на него написать еще 1 ajax и  отправлять запрос, результат был такой же)? 
сейчас при вводе правильного кода меня перекидывает на страницу 127.0.0.1:8000/endreg ,
и на ней мой Json { 'success': 'error'}
при вводе неправильного на туже страницу с формой.
Не понимаю, почему результат не вставляется на этой же странице.
Что надо сделать чтобы результат выводился на начальной странице 127.0.0.1:8000 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `$("#my_form").submit(function(event) { ...` вешает обработчик на DOM-элемент формы, который существует в момент выполнения этого кода, и который уничтожается, когда Вы делаете `parent.html(data.success);`.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#my_form", function(event) {
  ...
```

Comment: сейчас попробую, спасибо!
на 2 форму же надо будет еще 1 ajax?

Comment: @user355827 Если Вам нужен точно такой же ajax, то так он будет работать и для новой формы. Обработчик прикрепляется к документу, но выстреливает для событий на элементах, удовлетворяющих селектору.